# Strategies for working with slow databases with web apps

Tags: database, rest, symfony, architecture, json-ld

We're trying to figure out the best solution for working with a slow database on a live website.

The basic systems architecture is this:

- Slow (some reads and most writes are fast, others take multiple seconds) Postgres DB. We have no control over this.
- A monolithic offline system which accesses the Postgres DB. We have no control over this.
- Fast internal server(s) which may access the Postgres DB. We can develop and install software for this server.
- Fast web server(s) running a LAMP stack which may NOT access the Postgres DB, but may access the internal server. We can develop software for this server.
- Fast MySQL database(s) which may be accessed by anything. We have fully control over this.

We are developing a new web application to run on the web servers using Symfony 2.

Our initial plan was to create a RESTful API to sit on the internal server, which is consumed by the web app. The major issue we're facing is that the speed of the web app is constrained by the speed of the Postgres DB, which is unacceptable for users.

Does anyone know of any strategies to work around this speed issue?

Caching is the obvious solution and we can certainly have discussions about just how current the data needs to be, but in certain circumstances it must be absolutely up to the minute. For example, if a user saves some changes, these should appear immediately. We have considered having the API having its own fast data store which it updates asynchronously from Postgres. We could then perform all reads on this fast storage, committing writes to both that and Postgres. The worry is of course consistency in the data and an increased complexity to the system.

We are exploring using JSON-LD to represent the data as it is a good fit for what we're working with and using a standard, albeit a relatively young one, should ease any major architectural changes going forward, which may well happen. Since it could be put directly into a document store it would potentially simplify the process.

Our key goals here are:

- Provide a good experience to users.
- Create a system that is maintainable and straightforward to understand.

Any recommendations or suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main question to ask is: why is the Postgres DB so slow? Also from your explanation it isn't clear what all those systems are doing and what the dependicies/requirements are. For example, needs the data in the PostgresDB to be up to date? Is that the main DB? Is it an integration DB for the monolithic offline system?

If you can't change the slow Postgres DB, it has to be up to date to the minute and the website depends on it and must be up to the minute (in some cases) as well, you have a problem because that won't be possible. If the Postgres DB doesn't need to be up to the minute because it is just used by the offline app anyway, you can update that DB asynchrounosly and use your MySQL DBs in a way which gives you the necessary performance.

Given that you plan to use JSON-LD, I would love to hear more about the system you are building. Can you share some more information?

Comment: Thanks Markus. Having things up to the minute or not is exactly the problem. We think we've figured out a strategy that will work for our use case which is pretty much as you describe; updating the MySQL DB asynchronously to get changes from Postgres often, but not necessarily up to the minute. We will then have the API write to both the MySQL DB and Postgres so those changes will be up to the minute.

I may be able to tell you more elsewhere about our JSON-LD use :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you could potentially use couchdb. The premise of couch is that it's eventually consistent, but you have a local copy of the data you need to work with, and gets back to the app in an instant, and then updates the central repository as fast as it's able to.

It's also RESTful out of the box. The only thing you'd need to bridge is the postgres - couchdb connection.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if a user saves some changes, these should appear immediately.

This is also caching, so when an user update some data, caches (which now contains old data) expires (either Etag or manually remove cache)